# Upper limit for the number of fields and rules in an InfoPath form?

Tags: infopath, form, forms-library, time-out

We know of the [upper limit boundaries](http://www.khamis.net/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=91) of SharePoint itself but,

**what about the limits of a InfoPath form published to a SharePoint Form Library as a web form?**

**Does the size of the form have any bearing on its stability and publishing ability?**

I know that a [Time-out issue](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomizationprevious/thread/9f8a5ac7-8ddd-41aa-a188-13a1c66980d0) can occur in SharePoint but,

**what about hard limits with rules and fields?**

I noticed that after a certain point (around 200 fields/rules), I start getting this error,

> An unknown error has occurred. The form template has been published to
>   the server but it can only be opened in Info-path filler

What might this threshold be?